# Перенос содержимого одного файла в конец другого. C

Tags: c, файлы, posix

Мне необходимо в языке `с(си)` сделать программу: "которая добавляет содержимое одного файла в конец другого в обратном порядке." 
 
Как я сделал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    int main()
    {

        int fdIn;     
        int fdOut;   
        char buf[256]; 
        char InName[20];
        char OutName[20]; 
        ssize_t nRd;

        // Ввод имен входного и выходного файлов
        printf("Input. File name -> ");

        scanf("%s", InName);
        printf("Output. File name -> ");
        scanf("%s", OutName);

        // Открытия файла
        if((fdIn=open(InName, O_RDONLY))==-1)
        {
            perror("Error. Can't open an input file"); 
            return(-1);
        }
        if((fdOut=open(OutName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,644))== -1)
        {
            perror("Error. Can't open an output file");
            close(fdIn);
            return(-2);
        }

        // Цикл копирования
        while((nRd=read(fdIn, buf, 256))>0)
        {
        if(write(fdOut, buf, nRd)<nRd)
        {
            perror("Error recording"); close(fdIn); close(fdOut);
            return(-3);
        }
        }

        close(fdIn); close(fdOut);
        printf("Finished program\n");
        return(0);

    }
```

В итоге, у меня к примеру записано в файле "input.txt" какой-либо текст, и переносит сразу его в "output.txt", но как сделать чтобы переносило имено в output.txt в самый конец его файла в обратном порядке?
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: `FILE *fp = fopen("append.file", "a+");` попробуйте так.

Comment: fopen не поддерживают функцию (старый си).

Comment: Это откуда такое мнение? С стандарта 72 года не поддерживает?

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я в си практически не разбираюсь. Вы можете сказать, как мне переделать эту строку:   if((fdIn=open(InName, O_RDONLY))==-1)
Попробывал вот так - не получается:   if((fdIn=fopen(InName, "a+"))==-1)

Comment: В вашем случае используйте флаги для открытия файла в который нужно что то добавить - `O_WRONLY|O_APPEND`

Comment: И разница в реализации в том что open это кернел функция (syscall), а fopen это реализация поверх open.

Comment: Вот так, правильно? То не могу найти подходящий способ. 
    if((fdIn=fopen(InName, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND))==-1)
Понимаю, что очевидные вопросы задаю, но.. Ибо в инети не могу найти, по fopen описание этих флагов

Comment: Правильно почитать что либо на эту тему: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/open-rtlopen

Comment: Если вам нужны функции типа `open`, `read`, `write` и т.п., то помечайте свои вопросы тегом конкретной платформы. В С таких функций нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для записи в конец уже существующего файла, файл необходимо открывать с модификатором доступа `O_APPEND`, тогда курсор будет установлен в самый конец файла.
Пример: `fdOut = open(OutName, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND)`.

Для записи данных в обратном порядке, считанные данные перед записью необходимо развернуть и/или читать их с конца файла. Можно считать содержимое файла в массив, полученный массив развернуть и записать его, или просто записать считанный массив в обратном порядке. Можно при чтении использовать функцию `lseek`, позволяющую менять положение курсора в файле, таким образом читать его с конца.

Comment: Не подскажете.. Я прописал вот так: lseek(fdOut, 50L, SEEK_END);
В обратном порядке буквы не становятся..

Comment: @nikita Abramov, А с какого перепуга они в обратном порядке выстроятся? Оттого, что вы зачем-то установили файловый указатель на конец файла + 50? Автор ответа напрасно запутал вас советом читать с конца. Не надо этих высочайших технологий, просто читайте данные, меняйте порядок, записывайте.

Comment: Мне нужно "в обратном порядке" сделать. Как это вообще делать, не подскажешь? Через lseek не получается

Comment: @nikita Abramov, "в обратном порядке" именно это и означает, что тут может быть непонятного? Был первый байт, стал последний, а последний стал первым. Второй байт меняется местами с предпоследним, и так далее.

Comment: @nikitaAbramov, ну вот тебе такой пример побайтового чтения\записи с конца файла `// Цикл копирования for (long seek = -1;; seek--) { if (lseek(fdIn, seek, SEEK_END) == -1L) { break; } nRd = read(fdIn, buf, 1); if (write(fdOut, buf, nRd) < nRd) { perror("Error recording"); close(fdIn); close(fdOut); return(-3); } }`

Comment: @nikitaAbramov, `lseek` не задаёт направление чтения файла, а лишь позволяет сменить позицию в файле, чтение же продолжается слева направо, как обычно. Если делать это без lseek, то необходимо за раз считывать весь файл в массив, предварительно определив размер файла, затем элементы массива менять местами (с начала в конец и с конца в начало), разворачивая его, и развернутый массив целиком записывать в конец второго файла.